# Is there a way to use single-spa or micro front-end architecture to expose Quasar v1 app components to another app?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar, micro-frontend, single-spa

I want to expose some components from one quasar v1 app to another quasar v1 app using single-spa or any other micro front end architecture. Can anyone help with this as i am not able to find any solution online.

I tried module federation but quasar v1 uses vue 2 and webpack 4 and module federation isnt available in webpack 4 also the projects are now big so updating quasar version is making a lot of breaking changes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know what quasar is, but if it is a web application that is rendered via JavaScript (like React, Vue, Svelte, Solid, etc.), then it should be possible.  Read about single-spa parcels.